# CSS / jQuery: Dynamically updated text appears right of instead of inside circular progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar, jquery-animate

I am trying to implement an circular progress bar with animation and came across the plugin from the below resource.

I downloaded and included the plugin and used the source code (HTML and JS) from the demo page and with this it works.
However, my problem is that **the animated texts, i.e. the values that are generated through JS** (from 0 until the set percentage) **appear right from the circles / charts instead of inside them** (like in the demo).

**I am assuming I am missing some CSS here** but I am not sure what I need to add to move the values inside the circles / charts. The CSS from the source code has a comment saying that it is not required here.
Can someone please help me with this ?

**References:**

- https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Animated-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-Canvas-Circle-Progress.html
- https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-Canvas-Circle-Progress/

**HTML:**

```
<h1 style="margin-top:150px;">jQuery Circle Progress Demos</h1>
<div class="circles">
    <div class="first_circle">
        <span>no <br/> animation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="second_circle">
        <strong>0</strong>  <!-- This should appear inside the circle when being updated via JS -->
        <span>animation <br/> progress</span>
    </div>
    <div class="third_circle">
        <strong>0</strong>  <!-- This should appear inside the circle when being updated via JS -->
        <span>value <br/> progress</span>
    </div>
    <div class="forth_circle">
        <span>solid fill, <br/> custom angle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fifth_circle">
        <span>image fill, <br/> custom sizes</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.first_circle').circleProgress({
        value: 0.35,
        animation: false,
        fill: { gradient: ['#ff1e41', '#ff5f43'] }
    });
    $('.second_circle').circleProgress({
        value: 0.6
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
        $(this).find('strong').html(parseInt(100 * progress) + '<i>%</i>');
    });
    $('.third_circle').circleProgress({
        value: 0.8,
        fill: { gradient: ['#0681c4', '#07c6c1'] }
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
        $(this).find('strong').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(1));
    });
    $('.forth_circle').circleProgress({
        startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 3,
        value: .5,
        fill: { color: '#ffa500' }
    });
    $('.fifth_circle').circleProgress({
        value: 1,
        size: 60,
        thickness: 20,
        fill: {
            color: 'lime'
        }
    });
});
```

Many thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. First, you *are* missing some CSS for the demo to work. The demo links to a `page-styles.css` file that contains some CSS for the circles. And that brings up the second problem. Even if you just pasted the CSS, it wouldn't work "as-is" because `circle` needs to be its own class. In your markup and code, you combined two classes by adding an underscore between `first` and `circle`:

```
<div class="first_circle">
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="first circle">
```

So for your way to work, you'll either need to modify the CSS, or just separate the classes.

Here's an example with the appropriate CSS added (I just copied the relevant CSS from the `page-styles.css` file, not the entire thing):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.35,
    animation: false,
    fill: {
      gradient: ['#ff1e41', '#ff5f43']
    }
  });
  $('.second.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.6
  }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
    $(this).find('strong').html(parseInt(100 * progress) + '<i>%</i>');
  });
  $('.third.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.8,
    fill: {
      gradient: ['#0681c4', '#07c6c1']
    }
  }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
    $(this).find('strong').text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2)).substr(1));
  });
  $('.forth.circle').circleProgress({
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 3,
    value: .5,
    fill: {
      color: '#ffa500'
    }
  });
  $('.fifth.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 1,
    size: 60,
    thickness: 20,
    fill: {
      color: 'lime'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 6px 6px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.circle canvas {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.circle strong {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.circle strong i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.circle span {
  display: block;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-Canvas-Circle-Progress/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
<div class="circles">
  <div class="first circle">
    <span>no <br/> animation</span>
  </div>

  <div class="second circle">
    <strong></strong>
    <span>animation <br/> progress</span>
  </div>

  <div class="third circle">
    <strong></strong>
    <span>value <br/> progress</span>
  </div>

  <div class="forth circle">
    <span>solid fill, <br/> custom angle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="fifth circle">
    <span>image fill, <br/> custom sizes</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I go with this solution as this is exactly the issue I had and it works perfect this way.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* Examples */
(function($) {
  /*
   * Example 1:
   *
   * - no animation
   * - custom gradient
   *
   * By the way - you may specify more than 2 colors for the gradient
   */
  $('.first.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.35,
    animation: false,
    fill: {gradient: ['#ff1e41', '#ff5f43']}
  });

  /*
   * Example 2:
   *
   * - default gradient
   * - listening to `circle-animation-progress` event and display the animation progress: from 0 to 100%
   */
  $('.second.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.6
  }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
    $(this).find('strong').html(Math.round(100 * progress) + '<i>%</i>');
  });

  /*
   * Example 3:
   *
   * - very custom gradient
   * - listening to `circle-animation-progress` event and display the dynamic change of the value: from 0 to 0.8
   */
  $('.third.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.75,
    fill: {gradient: [['#0681c4', .5], ['#4ac5f8', .5]], gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4}
  }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
    $(this).find('strong').text(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(1));
  });

  /*
   * Example 4:
   *
   * - solid color fill
   * - custom start angle
   * - custom line cap
   * - dynamic value set
   */
  var c4 = $('.forth.circle');

  c4.circleProgress({
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4 * 3,
    value: 0.5,
    lineCap: 'round',
    fill: {color: '#ffa500'}
  });

  // Let's emulate dynamic value update
  setTimeout(function() { c4.circleProgress('value', 0.7); }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() { c4.circleProgress('value', 1.0); }, 1100);
  setTimeout(function() { c4.circleProgress('value', 0.5); }, 2100);

  /*
   * Example 5:
   *
   * - image fill; image should be squared; it will be stretched to SxS size, where S - size of the widget
   * - fallback color fill (when image is not loaded)
   * - custom widget size (default is 100px)
   * - custom circle thickness (default is 1/14 of the size)
   * - reverse drawing mode
   * - custom animation start value
   * - usage of "data-" attributes
   */
  $('.fifth.circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.7
    // all other config options were taken from "data-" attributes
    // options passed in config object have higher priority than "data-" attributes
    // "data-" attributes are taken into account only on init (not on update/redraw)
    // "data-fill" (and other object options) should be in valid JSON format
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  padding-top: 40px;
  font: 15px/1.3 Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: orange;
}

.new-tab-link {
  padding-right: 14px;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3ggXDSIzCeRHfQAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAAA9SURBVBjTY2RAA/+XMvxHF2NkwAOwacCq4P9Shv8suFQzRiNsYUEXwKoJ2VhkNrIaJgYiAAs2N2BVRMirAD6JHi10MCdVAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat right center;
}

.page-title {
  font: 400 40px/1.5 Open Sans, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.circles {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 6px 6px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.circle canvas {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.circle strong {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.circle strong i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.circle span {
  display: block;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

p {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>

<div class="circles">
    <div class="first circle">
      <span>no <br> animation</span>
    </div>

    <div class="second circle">
      <strong></strong>
      <span>animation <br> progress</span>
    </div>

    <div class="third circle">
      <strong></strong>
      <span>value <br> progress</span>
    </div>

    <div class="forth circle">
      <span>custom angle, <br> value update</span>
    </div>

    <div
      class="fifth circle"
      data-value="0.9"
      data-size="60"
      data-thickness="20"
      data-animation-start-value="1.0"
      data-fill="{
        &quot;color&quot;: &quot;rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)&quot;,
        &quot;image&quot;: &quot;http://i.imgur.com/pT0i89v.png&quot;
      }"
      data-reverse="true"
    >
      <span>image fill, <br> custom sizes</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I just put it together from the demo, I think you'd missed something out or deleted something as it was throwing errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is fantastic !